# changing $HOME directory name

Tags: users, xfce, home, startx

I'm Using Arch Linux + Xfce4 (Edit: running as VBox OS guest) and I wanted to change a username and it's home directory accordingly. I followed these steps as root:

1.Renamed the home directory

```
# mv /home/oldusername /home/newusername
```

2.Changed user's login name and home directory:

```
# usermod -l newusername oldusername
# usermod -d /home/newusername newusername
```

3.Changed user's default group name

```
# groupmod -n newgroupname oldgroupname
```

All that went fine, I could log in as newusername and check that the env variables $USER, $HOME are ok.

But when I run "startx", the X session does not start. Then I shutdown the system and as root again I rename the home directory back to /home/oldusername. Then I login as newusername and this time startx succeeds. Why is that? only the dirname is changing, all other files (.xinitrc, etc.) are the same..

Comment: does `grep oldusername .xinitrc` holds any results?

Comment: no, there should be no username harcoded in any files/scripts. I forgot to mention that I'm running the Arch Linux as a guest OS in virtualbox, I will edit my question to add that.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there is a configuration somewhere pointing to that user. I have a few suggestions you can try.

First, make sure your new `$HOME` has the right ownership.

Secondly, read and post the error message given by Xorg.

Thirdly, search your `$HOME` directory for any configuration files that hold the old `$HOME` path.

```
cd $HOME
grep -r "olduser" .
```

It would be a good idea to pipe the search to less or redirect to file.

If you can't find anything in your `$HOME` the next step is to try `/etc/`. That is generally where all configurations should be.

If that holds nothing, do the same on `/`.

Comment: I've deleted the $HOME/.config/xfce4/ directory just in case but it didn't help. Since it was a test system I think I will delete that user and create a new one.

Comment: @rodrunner I edited my answer